# How can I use Instabug with older support library and Holo Theme

Tags: android, instabug

I want to use Instabug with older version of support library (appcompat-v7 / support-v4) because our application is not ready to use Material design. But when I use `InstabugAppCompatActivity` (or any other type) I get material design into my application because of linking newer support library with linking `com.instabug.library.instabugsupport`.
Any ideas how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this include (or newer version of **instabugbasic**): 
`compile 'com.instabug.library:instabugbasic:1.3.8'`
Then you need to create your InstabugActivity extending your ActionBarActivity and override few methods.

```
public class BaseInstabugActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

InstabugActivityDelegate mDelegate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDelegate = new InstabugActivityDelegate(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDelegate.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mDelegate.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDelegate.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    mDelegate.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}   }
```

The rest of integration is the same as with official guide. So don't forget to inicialize Instabug in Application class and add InstabugFeedbackActivity into your manifest. Maybe you will need to use own android:theme with InstabugFeedbackActivity in manifest.

Comment: Is this valid now too? I can only find `compile 'com.instabug.library:instabug:4.0.7'
` in their docs. `InstabugAppCompatActivity` doesn't seem to be present.